# RNA Seq in R - How do I match ncol and nrow numbers between a CSV Table and Metadata?

Tags: r, bioinformatics, bioconductor

In RStudio, I'm trying to get the metadata aligned to the DataFrame of the CSV File. I'll outline the code here + the error it outputs

```
> colData(se) <- DataFrame(sampleTable)
Error in `colData<-`(`*tmp*`, value = new("DFrame", rownames = c("RP11-126O22.8",  : 
  nrow of supplied 'colData' must equal ncol of object
```

My question is how I can fix this error, and match the ColData nrow to the ncol of the object? If you need further information, please read ahead.

The sampleTable is just a read-in of the csv file for reference. (If you need to download the CSV File to reproduce the data it's [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/download/?acc=GSE100745&format=file&file=GSE100745%5FRNAseq%2Ecsv%2Egz))

```
sampleTable <- read.csv("GSE100745_RNAseq.csv", row.names = 1, strip.white=TRUE)
```

Here's my outputs for the "se" variable which shows the rows and columns, for reference. (For additional info)

```
> dim(se)
[1] 63677    14
> assayNames(se)
[1] "counts"
> head(assay(se), 30)
                SRR5799988.1.bam SRR5799989.1.bam SRR5799990.1.bam
ENSG00000000003               33               44               35
ENSG00000000005                0                2                0
ENSG00000000419              200              378              366
ENSG00000000457              304              263              453
ENSG00000000460              178              122              362
ENSG00000000938                2                6                2
ENSG00000000971                6                2                0
ENSG00000001036               33               72               55
ENSG00000001084              229              442              477
ENSG00000001167             1008              823             1010
ENSG00000001460              167              120              167
ENSG00000001461             2431             1601             2349
ENSG00000001497             1255             1332             1747
ENSG00000001561              227              192              253
ENSG00000001617                0                2                0
ENSG00000001626                2               17                2
ENSG00000001629             1514             1535             1604
ENSG00000001630                9                0                6
ENSG00000001631             1275             1165             1731
ENSG00000002016              497              422              530
ENSG00000002079                9               13               25
ENSG00000002330               11                9               22
ENSG00000002549              247              316              265
ENSG00000002586               91              253              222
ENSG00000002587                2               12                2
ENSG00000002726                0                0                0
ENSG00000002745               12               15               11
ENSG00000002746                5                5                1
ENSG00000002822              238              219              232
ENSG00000002834             2495             1471             1806
                SRR5799991.1.bam SRR5799992.1.bam SRR5799993.1.bam
ENSG00000000003               18               45               25
ENSG00000000005                1                0                0
ENSG00000000419              385              382              258
ENSG00000000457              460              428              285
ENSG00000000460              149              189              172
ENSG00000000938                7                8                4
ENSG00000000971               26                0                2
ENSG00000001036               49               38               38
ENSG00000001084              310              369              267
ENSG00000001167              996             1297             1000
ENSG00000001460              215              135              195
ENSG00000001461             1986             2439             2084
ENSG00000001497              940             1431             1094
ENSG00000001561              200              233              234
ENSG00000001617               10                0                0
ENSG00000001626               15                7                1
ENSG00000001629             1384             1669             1499
ENSG00000001630                6                7                7
ENSG00000001631             1078             1486             1249
ENSG00000002016              481              506              427
ENSG00000002079               27                7               20
ENSG00000002330                9               11               14
ENSG00000002549              251              230              327
ENSG00000002586              326              233              315
ENSG00000002587               19                5                5
ENSG00000002726                9                6                2
ENSG00000002745                9               19               15
ENSG00000002746               31                4                2
ENSG00000002822              174              279              168
ENSG00000002834             2360             2418             2363
                SRR5799994.1.bam SRR5799995.1.bam SRR5799996.1.bam
ENSG00000000003               11                0                0
ENSG00000000005                5                0                0
ENSG00000000419              480              371              394
ENSG00000000457              433              345              390
ENSG00000000460              909              561              514
ENSG00000000938             1103             1353             1278
ENSG00000000971               14                0                0
ENSG00000001036              366              135              143
ENSG00000001084              741              711              604
ENSG00000001167             1286             1267             1115
ENSG00000001460              149              135              122
ENSG00000001461             1227             1135             1621
ENSG00000001497             1326              902             1048
ENSG00000001561              829              451              526
ENSG00000001617                7                3                0
ENSG00000001626               19                0                0
ENSG00000001629             3264             2749             2099
ENSG00000001630                7                2                5
ENSG00000001631             1356             1308             1016
ENSG00000002016              694              371              607
ENSG00000002079               15                2                4
ENSG00000002330               35               38               40
ENSG00000002549              847              862              551
ENSG00000002586             1621             1235             1899
ENSG00000002587               15                2                0
ENSG00000002726                7                0                0
ENSG00000002745                7                0                9
ENSG00000002746               23                2                2
ENSG00000002822              220              206              427
ENSG00000002834             7970             6724             6701
                SRR5799997.1.bam SRR5799998.1.bam SRR5799999.1.bam
ENSG00000000003               16               18                6
ENSG00000000005                0                0                0
ENSG00000000419              316              287              506
ENSG00000000457              410              313              188
ENSG00000000460              268              139               88
ENSG00000000938              520               49              193
ENSG00000000971                8              102               12
ENSG00000001036               47               33               69
ENSG00000001084              497              383              368
ENSG00000001167             1473             1063              974
ENSG00000001460              118               70               40
ENSG00000001461             1033             1256              861
ENSG00000001497             1218              839              998
ENSG00000001561              715              298              242
ENSG00000001617                0                0                2
ENSG00000001626                2                0                3
ENSG00000001629             1811             1638             1215
ENSG00000001630               12                2                0
ENSG00000001631             1332             1049             1028
ENSG00000002016              364              374              321
ENSG00000002079                2                0                3
ENSG00000002330               12               21               20
ENSG00000002549              565              386              895
ENSG00000002586             1023              607              742
ENSG00000002587                2                1                8
ENSG00000002726                0                2                3
ENSG00000002745                6                8                2
ENSG00000002746                0                2                0
ENSG00000002822              256              115              162
ENSG00000002834             2976             2520             1203
                SRR5800000.1.bam SRR5800001.1.bam
ENSG00000000003                6                3
ENSG00000000005                0                0
ENSG00000000419              336              183
ENSG00000000457              270               97
ENSG00000000460              111               48
ENSG00000000938               22              102
ENSG00000000971               36               79
ENSG00000001036               42                1
ENSG00000001084              318              158
ENSG00000001167              843              333
ENSG00000001460              106                1
ENSG00000001461              899              300
ENSG00000001497              498              442
ENSG00000001561              231              126
ENSG00000001617                0                0
ENSG00000001626                1                0
ENSG00000001629             1032              672
ENSG00000001630                5                4
ENSG00000001631              830              435
ENSG00000002016              352               76
ENSG00000002079                0                1
ENSG00000002330                5                0
ENSG00000002549              257              395
ENSG00000002586              608              295
ENSG00000002587                0                0
ENSG00000002726                0                0
ENSG00000002745                0                0
ENSG00000002746                0               25
ENSG00000002822              110               32
ENSG00000002834             2036              805
> colSums(assay(se))
SRR5799988.1.bam SRR5799989.1.bam SRR5799990.1.bam SRR5799991.1.bam 
        32365618         35860036         42709011         34315244 
SRR5799992.1.bam SRR5799993.1.bam SRR5799994.1.bam SRR5799995.1.bam 
        33769162         33898292         42319181         39874382 
SRR5799996.1.bam SRR5799997.1.bam SRR5799998.1.bam SRR5799999.1.bam 
        36856010         37167253         32257010         29211520 
SRR5800000.1.bam SRR5800001.1.bam 
        27121525         15545235 
> rowRanges(se)
GRangesList object of length 63677:
$ENSG00000000003
GRanges object with 17 ranges and 2 metadata columns:
       seqnames            ranges strand |   exon_id       exon_name
          <Rle>         <IRanges>  <Rle> | <integer>     <character>
   [1]     chrX 99883667-99884983      - |    667145 ENSE00001459322
   [2]     chrX 99885756-99885863      - |    667146 ENSE00000868868
   [3]     chrX 99887482-99887565      - |    667147 ENSE00000401072
   [4]     chrX 99887538-99887565      - |    667148 ENSE00001849132
   [5]     chrX 99888402-99888536      - |    667149 ENSE00003554016
   ...      ...               ...    ... .       ...             ...
  [13]     chrX 99890555-99890743      - |    667157 ENSE00003662440
  [14]     chrX 99891188-99891686      - |    667158 ENSE00001886883
  [15]     chrX 99891605-99891803      - |    667159 ENSE00001855382
  [16]     chrX 99891790-99892101      - |    667160 ENSE00001863395
  [17]     chrX 99894942-99894988      - |    667161 ENSE00001828996
  -------
  seqinfo: 265 sequences from an unspecified genome; no seqlengths

...
<63676 more elements>
> str(metadata(rowRanges(se)))
List of 1
 $ genomeInfo:List of 13
  ..$ Db type                                 : chr "TxDb"
  ..$ Supporting package                      : chr "GenomicFeatures"
  ..$ Data source                             : chr "/Volumes/CHACAL_0/T_Cell_RNA-seq/BAM/Local_alignment/Homo_sapiens.GRCh37.75.gtf"
  ..$ Organism                                : chr NA
  ..$ Taxonomy ID                             : chr NA
  ..$ miRBase build ID                        : chr NA
  ..$ Genome                                  : chr NA
  ..$ Nb of transcripts                       : chr "215170"
  ..$ Db created by                           : chr "GenomicFeatures package from Bioconductor"
  ..$ Creation time                           : chr "2020-08-23 23:34:40 -0400 (Sun, 23 Aug 2020)"
  ..$ GenomicFeatures version at creation time: chr "1.40.1"
  ..$ RSQLite version at creation time        : chr "2.2.0"
  ..$ DBSCHEMAVERSION                         : chr "1.2"
> colData(se)
DataFrame with 14 rows and 0 columns
```

Answer (score 0):

Sample names within your data has to be the same that your metadata information. As you can see, *SRR5799988.1.bam, SRR5799989.1.bam, SRR5799990.1.bam, etc.* are totally different from *Naive_AKJ_D3630, Naive_YF653, Naive_YF661, etc.*